# How to change the color of <f:facet> header?

Tags: css, jsf, facet

Exactly, how can I do this? Tried:

```
<f:facet id="form" name="header" class="customHeader">
   <h:outputText value="HELLO!"/>
</f:facet>
```

and my CSS:

```
.customHeader th{
    background-color:  activeborder;
    background-image: none;
}
```

I remebered to include CSS file into JSF page:

```
<link type="text/css" ref="stylesheet" href="./newcss.css"/>
```

But no result, I cant change the header color, I simply does not see any change. Any help?

Heres the generated HTML code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="j_idt2">
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <link type="text/css" 
              ref="stylesheet" 
              href="./newcss.css" />
    </head
    ><body>
        <form id="j_idt5" 
              name="j_idt5" 
              method="post" 
              action="/HTableJSF/faces/newjsf.xhtml" 
              enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <input type="hidden" name="j_idt5" value="j_idt5" />
            <table style="background-color: black">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="1" scope="colgroup">HELLO!</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span class="row1">HELLO</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" 
                   name="javax.faces.ViewState" 
                   id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" 
                   value="-3603525257247985306:-5087066467544098625" 
                   autocomplete="off" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check HTML structure of the response. Check that the stylesheet is really included (`body{background-color:red;}`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `headerClass` on [`h:column`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/column.html) :

```
<h:column headerClass="customHeader">
    <f:facet name="header">
        HELLO!
    </f:facet>
</h:column>
```

In this case for specific columns `<th class="customHeader">` will be generated.

So, you need to change css selector. Either remove `th`:

`.customHeader {/**/}`

or change it from [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) to `element.class`

`th.customHeader {/**/}`

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been looking for this for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to put your CSS class (class="customHeader") one component above from the facet

ex:

```
<p:panel styleClass="customHeader">
  <f:facet name="header">
    ....
  </f:facet>
</p:panel>
```

or

```
<p:column styleClass="customHeader">
  <f:facet name="header">
    ....
  </f:facet>
</p:panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

In what browser/system are you working?

`activeborder` is the color of the default active border. But consider that Named System Colors are deprecated in CSS3, so is not standard. You can't be sure if all operating systems support all the defined system colors.

Try something like:

```
background-color: cyan;
```

or

```
background-color: #00FFFF;
```

Comment: Tried with FF and Chormium. Changed to cyan, with no result